# Prevent user start-up items from launching in current session?

Tags: boot

In older versions of Windows I remember that you could hold down the ctrl key at logon, and this would prevent your user start-up items from launching, just for that one session.

Is there any way to replicate this sort of on-the-fly, temporary disabling of the start-up items nowadays, in Windows 10?

Thank you.

Comment: See this, it works in W7 and probably will in W10>>>>>https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/how-to-disable-startup-applications-using-shift-key.html

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately holding down shift didn't work for me.

Comment: Only way I have found is to use msconfig>General Tab>tick selective startup> and untick startup items.